# ck editor forcefully removing my html and body tags

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor, html-editor

I am trying to edit an entire html using fck editor. So that should contain tags like html, body ,DOCTYPE etc. But my problem is when I submit the data, fckeditor forcefully remove the above tags from the content. I want to avoid this. Is there any configuration issue there.

-Arun

Answer (score 4):

look at this config option.  CKEDITOR.config.fullPage.  I believe it will permit you to edit the full page (and will preserve the contents)  (i haven't used it.)

Answer (score 0):

'ckEditor' (as it's now known) shouldn't allow html/script tags directly within the content. However if you have the latest version there is a 'source' view which allows all the source to be edited directly and may give you what you want.

Comment: I am trying to edit a physical html file. That is I will read the full content of a an html file and show it in ckeditor. When click update it will overwrite the physical file. So I want to keep those tags.

Answer (score 0):

### Arun User this one .This is best solution for you.

```
var CKcontent = false ;

$(document).ready(function(){

    // setup ckeditor and its configurtion
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content1',
        {
                //fullPage : true,
                customConfig : 'config.js' ,  
                toolbar :  'BasicToolbar'  ,
                height : "300"


        });


});
```

1. Set only **fullpage : false** if not show HTML content otherwise set true

### Note: it implemented by me in our development